# Pass `environmentObject` data to another class (singleton)

Tags: swiftui, singleton, observableobject, observedobject, environmentobject

I have an `observableObject` class that holds some data.

**Observable Class**

```
class UserManager:ObservableObject {
    @Published
    var profile:userProfileModel = userProfileModel()
    
    @Published
    var settings:Settings = Settings()
    
    @Published var currentView:String
    @Published var isLoggedIn:Bool
```

and I create and pass it from `SceneDelegate` as an `environmentObject` to view hierarchy.

**SceneDelegate**

```
@StateObject var userManager = UserManager()
let contentView = loginRoot().environmentObject(userManager)
```

The problem is that I have a singleton class that syncs with the server and I need to update the data in the `UserManager` class.

**Singleton Class**

```
public class UserModelAPI {
    @ObservedObject var userManager: UserManager = UserManager()
    public static let shared = UserModelAPI()
    
    func syncServer() {
         userManager.isLoggedIn = true
    }
```

but it doesn't work at all.
I can not publish changes from the singleton class.

Answer (score 0):

inside your singleton you have a new UserManager(), it is different from the SceneDelegate "@StateObject var userManager ...",
that's probably why it does not work as you expect.
Try this in your SceneDelegate:

```
@StateObject var userManager = UserModelAPI.shared.userManager
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this is going to work, the `UserManager` class holds the data which the UI depends on, and at some points, I have to monitor for any changes.
also, in `UserModelAPI` I have to access that data generated before and make some changes to it.